# Spring Boot and Thymeleaf Question - Model Specific Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf

I am a beginner to Spring Boot and Thymeleaf and i have a question and would appreciate it if any experienced developers could help me out! I have a EmployeeController -> EmployeeService -> EmployeeRepository setup! Currently i have a getMapping to retrieve an employee! Here is my class below:

Employee Controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/find")
    public String findEmployee(@RequestParam("employeeId") int theId, Model model) {

        Employee employee = employeeService.findById(theId);

        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);

        return "/employees";

    }
```

So with the above, i am able to access the object on with Thymeleaf with the "employee" attribute as such `th:object="${employee}`

However how to i pass in ab object as an attribute in the model that i do not have a entity class for?

for example, lets say i have a getMapping method that return a complex query like getting the TOP 5 SKUs of a product by sales and the table result for it will have a column of sku and unit_sold! The above getMapping, the `employeeService.findById(theId)` returns a 'Employee' type and i was able to capture it as i do have an Employee class! And i was able to add the employee to the model attribute to use it in Thymeleaf!

However for the complex query, i do not have a class for it and i will not be able to capture it! How do i pass it as a model attribute so that i can use it as an object in Thymeleaf? Do i have to create a class like bellow and capture it and pass it into the model as an attribute?

```java
public class Employee {

    private String sku;
    private int unitSold;

}
```

any advice would be really appreciated

I tried creating a Entity class just for the result but not working

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

In these cases the general best practice would be to use a **DTO** (Data Transfer Object).

Let's say your Employee model looks like this:

```
    public class Employee {

    private String sku;
    private int unitSold;
    private String name;
    private String age;
}
```

But you want to give thymeleaf a different looking model, like this one:

```
    public class EmployeeDto {

    private String sku;
    private int unitSold;
    private LocalDate startOfPeriod;
    private LocalDate endOfPeriod;
}
```

You could use this DTO Class to add to the Thymeleaf model.

You also wouldn't need a repository class, you can use the **JdbcTemplate** for SQL or the **MongoTemplate** for MongoDB to Query for the Dto

```
   public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<EmployeeDto> getAllSales() {
        String sql = "SELECT sku, unit_sold, start_of_period, end_of_period FROM sales_data";

        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, salesRowMapper());
    }

    private RowMapper<EmployeeDto> salesRowMapper() {
        return (rs, rowNum) -> {
            EmployeeDto salesData = new EmployeeDto();
            salesData.setSku(rs.getString("sku"));
            salesData.setUnitSold(rs.getInt("unit_sold"));
            salesData.setStartOfPeriod(rs.getObject("start_of_period", LocalDate.class));
            salesData.setEndOfPeriod(rs.getObject("end_of_period", LocalDate.class));
            return salesData;
        };
    }
   }
```

or using MongoDB and MongoTemplate

```
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public List<EmployeeDto> getAllSales() {
        // Assuming the collection name is 'employee'
        List<EmployeeDto> salesData = mongoTemplate.findAll(EmployeeDto.class, "employee");
        return salesData;
    }
```

This can then be added to the thymeleaf template engine as normal

```
model.addAttibute("employeeDto", this.employeeService.getAllSales());
```

This would be considered the most straightforward solution.

### Solution 2

An alternative solution to this problem that doesn't require a dto would be to use your Jdbc or Mongo Template to get the results as a **Map**.

```
    public String getAllSales() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM sales"; // Adjust SQL query as needed

        // Execute the query and retrieve the result as a list of maps
        List<Map<String, Object>> salesData = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
        return salesData; 
    }
```

```
    public String getAllSales() {
        // Query without criteria to fetch all documents
        Query query = new Query();

        // Execute the query and retrieve the result as a list of maps
        List<Map> salesData = mongoTemplate.find(query, Map.class, "sales");

        return salesData;
    }
```

Personally I would recommend using Dto's, but this is also a valid solution.